# Office365 "addFileAttachmentAsync" error

Tags: office365, office365-apps, office-js, outlook-web-addins

I'm currently experiencing issues with attachment addition in an Office365

```
function attachFiles() {
    Office.context.mailbox.item.addFileAttachmentAsync('https://www.google.es/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png', filename, { asyncContext: null }, testCallback);
}

function testCallback(result) {
    if (result.error) {
        console.log(result.error);
    } else {
        console.log("Attachment added");
    }
}
```

The code above will always result (after some timeout) in the following error:

```
OSF.DDA.Error {name: "InternalFormatError", message: "Hubo un error de formato interno.", code: 9002}
```

The code has been tested days ago without any issues and now it has stopped working.

**UPDATE 08/02/2016:**
addFileAttachmentAsync seems to be globally broken on Office365. Not even their own samples on github are working (https://github.com/OfficeDev/Outlook-Power-Hour-Code-Samples). Looking for a workaround...

**UPDATE 08/02/2016 15:41 GMT+1**

I've tested another addin from the Office365 addin store that uses the addFileAttachmentAsync API call and it doesn't work either (Dropbox to Outlook Import https://store.office.com/dropbox-to-outlook-import-WA104379875.aspx?assetid=WA104379875&sourcecorrid=866179b6-8806-4f78-b927-320db5dd6282&searchapppos=4). If there's anyone who could test it from another region & email to confirm it's not an issue with my account I'd be so thankful. Here's a screenshot of the same error:

[image: addFileAttachmentAsync failing on "Dropbox To Outlook Import"]

Comment: Hello, we have identified a bug with addFileAttachmentAsync API that we are working on fixing right away. Thank you for your patience :)

Comment: The issue should now be fixed - do you still run in to issues?

Answer (score 0):

This may due to network connectivity issue, re-try to upload. Also, make sure that you are not exceeding the maximum limit of file size to upload on your office 365 tenant.

Comment: Hello and thank you for your response. File size doesn't seem to be the issue neither connectivity and retrying to upload hasn't worked yet...

Comment: Run Fiddler and check out the detailed error there, it might be an issue related to an updated security policy that doesn't allow your app to load external content (Cross domain policy) issues.

Comment: I did check on Fiddler and there's no request being made. I also tried serving an url pointing to a local file on the same domain (which used to work before) and it didn't work either. It seems to me that the office365 messed something up in the last deploy, which would explain that it stopped working progressively while being deployed to the various endpoints.

PD. Even though the POST request is not being made to the backend I checked the message being sent by the addin component to the container window using the HTML Window.postMessage() API (i'll attach a sample on the next comment).

Comment: Received messsage from https://localhost:44302, data = {"_messageType":0,"_actionName":"AddFileAttachmentAsync","_conversationId":"-2d2979a3_-7617f1d8_1454937725890","_correlationId":45,"_origin":"https://localhost:44302/App/Home/Home.html?et=&_host_Info=Outlook|Web|16.01…7725890|ocii0|https://outlook.office.com/owa/?realm=mywebpage.com#path=/mail","_data":{"uri":"https://www.google.es/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png","name":"googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png"},"_actionType":0}

Comment: If the request is not being made, this means there is an issue in your code, please test out your requests to graph api explorer here in this link: https://graphexplorer2.azurewebsites.net/  - This should give you an indication if your request is correct in the first place or not.

Comment: Or maybe it's not an issue in my code but rather a bug in Office365. The fact that their own sample code doesn't work leads me to think so. I just tested another addin that is in the store and uses the same function of the API and it doesn't work either. I'll update the original question.

Comment: some samples are really old, you have to make sure it connect to the right endpoints. this is my 2 cents for you.